# Duplex printing settings ignored when printing on Kyosera network printers via ipptool / cups

Tags: command-line, networking, printing, duplex-printing

I have added several Kyosera network printers on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS via CUPS web admin console.

They are all set up and working but **double-sided printing settings are ignored** and documents printed one-sided.

**This is what tests show:**

The test below

```
sudo ipptool -tv ipp://KM963697.local:631/ipp/print get-printer-attributes.test
```

results in following info saying **two-sided priting IS supported**:

```
job-creation-attributes-supported (1setOf keyword) = orientation-requested,copies,finishings,ipp-attribute-fidelity,job-name,media,media-col,operation-requested,output-bin,print-quality,printer-resolution,sides,print-color-mode,multiple-document-handling,page-ranges,page-content-optimize,page-scaling,feed-orientation,overrides,job-mandatory-attributes

sides-supported (1setOf keyword) = one-sided,two-sided-short-edge,two-sided-long-edge

sides-default (keyword) = one-sided
```

Doing print test of a 2-paged PDF document (https://www.delta-intkey.com/www/printtest.pdf) via

```
ipptool -tv -f printtest.pdf ipp://KM963697.local:631/ipp/print printjob.ipp
```

results in the document printed **one-sided** and **ipptool** reported the following:
"printjob.ipp":

```
        Print-Job:
            attributes-charset (charset) = utf-8
            attributes-natural-language (naturalLanguage) = en
            **sides (keyword) = two-sided-long-edge**
            printer-uri (uri) = ipp://KM963697.local:631/ipp/print
            job-name (nameWithoutLanguage) = printtest.pdf
            document-name (nameWithoutLanguage) = printtest.pdf
            copies (integer) = 1
            color (boolean) = false
            number-up (integer) = 1
            orientation-requested (enum) = portrait
            print-scaling (keyword) = fit
        printjob                                                             [PASS]
            RECEIVED: 256 bytes in response
            **status-code = successful-ok-ignored-or-substituted-attributes (successful-ok-ignored-or-substituted-attributes)**
            attributes-charset (charset) = utf-8
            attributes-natural-language (naturalLanguage) = en-us
            **sides (unsupported) = unsupported**
            copies (unsupported) = unsupported
            color (unsupported) = unsupported
            number-up (unsupported) = unsupported
            orientation-requested (unsupported) = unsupported
            job-id (integer) = 1014
            job-uri (uri) = ipps://KM963697:443/jobs/1014
            job-state (enum) = pending
            job-state-reasons (keyword) = job-incoming
```

Correspondent **printjob.ipp** contents is:

```
    {
      OPERATION Print-Job
      GROUP operation-attributes-tag
        ATTR charset attributes-charset utf-8
        ATTR language attributes-natural-language en
        ATTR keyword sides two-sided-long-edge
        ATTR uri printer-uri $uri
        ATTR name job-name $filename
        ATTR name document-name $filename
        ATTR integer copies 1
        ATTR boolean color false
        ATTR integer number-up 1
        ATTR enum orientation-requested 3
      FILE $filename
    
      GROUP job-attributes-tag
        ATTR keyword print-scaling "fit"
    }
```

Versions of software used: *Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, cups 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1*

Printer models are: *Kyocera ECOSYS P3150dn, Kyocera ECOSYS M2235dn, Kyocera ECOSYS P2040dn*
Their drivers updated from Kyosera site: https://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.ru/ru/support/downloads.name-L3J1L3J1L21mcC9FQ09TWVNNMjIzNURO.html

Greatly appreciate any advice how to enable duplex priting on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved in the following way:

1. Properly installed manufacturer drivers with dependencies using gdebi
2. Configured these drivers in CUPS, adding them via ipp using network ip address of the printers
3. Using lp tool for printing using printer name from CUPS, instead of ipptool

It seems ipptool bypassed the CUPS configuration and used default driverless printer while printing via ipptool and printer address ipp://

The problem has been show up in CUPS after printing since there were no active jobs appearing there when used ipptool. After swithcing to lp and proper printer setup via CUPS jobs start appearing there.